# Laravel - super long relation (it doesn't feel right)

Tags: php, laravel

Okay, This is my method:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $ent, $room, $obj)
{
    $input = $request->except(['_token']);

    Enterprise::where('bedrijfsnaam', $ent)->first()->rooms()->where('name', $room)->first()->objects()->where('name', $obj)->first()->update($input);

    return redirect('/enterprise/'.$ent.'/room/'.$room);
}
```

As you can see, at `Enterprise::where()` I have a really long relation, But it doesn't feel right to have such a long relation. Is it just okay to have one this large or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Use scope in your model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it is difficult to say whether you could simplify your database schema without actually knowing what your relations/models are. However, in some cases complex relationships like this are perfectly ok. In this case, I would define some more descriptive methods on your models to abstract the queries you are building in your controllers.

Instead of `Enterprise::where('bedrijfsnaam', $ent)->first()->rooms()->where('name', $room)->first()->objects()->where('name', $obj)->first()->update($input);`, maybe you could simplify it to something like:

`Enterprise::where('bedrijfsnaam', $ent)->first()->getRoomByName($name)->getObjectByName($obj)->update($input);`